# Can anyone explain why below o/p

Tags: java, inheritance

Parent class :

```
public class Parent {
public void run()
{
    walk();
    System.out.println("Parent run");
}

public void walk()
{
    System.out.println("Parent walk");
}
```

Child Class :

```
public class Child extends Parent {

public void run()
{
    super.run();
    System.out.println("child run");
}

public void walk()
{
    super.walk();
    System.out.println("child walk");
}



public class FirstJava {
public static void main(String[] a) {
    Child c=new Child();
    c.run();
}
```

I am gettting below o/p

Parent walk

child walk

Parent run

child run

Here when i call *walk()* its going for *walk()* of Child. 
Why not for *walk()* of parent? 
While calling *walk()* which object its refering to and why? any one explain why??
how come its calling both the methods from child as well as parent.

Comment: what about to look at `super` behavior ?

Comment: yes... just wanted to know why its calling child class methods?

Comment: is it clear ? (I edited my answer)

Comment: thanks for your response.....but i am getting below o/p. I am gettting below o/p

Parent walk
child walk
Parent run
child run

Comment: yes, and my answer explains why

Comment: Easy, @bruno, please, I recommend that the OP waits a day or two to see if other answers are posted before deciding which one is the most helpful. Accepting an answer eventually is good style, of course.

Answer (score 3):

in

```
 Child c=new Child();
 c.run();
```

you apply *run* corresponding to the type of the value in *c*, because *c* values a *Child* and *run* is defined on it you call the operation *run* defined on *Child* being :

```
public void run()
{
    super.run();
    System.out.println("child run");
}
```

`super.run()` applies the operation corresponding to the parent class, because the parent class of *Child* is *Parent* and *run* is defined on it you call :

```
public void run()
{
    walk();
    System.out.println("Parent run");
}
```

the operation *walk* is applied depending on the *real* type of the instance being *Child* so you call :

```
public void walk()
{
    super.walk();
    System.out.println("child walk");
}
```

like before because of `super` that calls the operation on *Parent* :

```
public void walk()
{
    System.out.println("Parent walk");
}
```

printing *Parent walk* then you come back in *Child walk* printing *child walk* then come back in *Parent run* printing *Parent run* then come back in *Child run* printing *child run*

---

After your edit

> Here when i call walk() its going for walk() of Child. Why not for walk() of parent? While calling walk() which object its refering to and why?

As I already say this is because the called method is determined (*at the execution*) by the **real** type of the instance, and in that case the instance is a *Child*, so the called method is the *walk* defined on *Child* and not the one on *Parent*. Of course if there is no *walk* defined on *Child* it would be the one defined on *Parent*. All the method are applied on the unique instance you created in *main* and being a *Child*

Of course if *walk* is a method for the class *Parent* (e.g. *static*) rather than for its instances that changes all and `walk()` in *run* of *Parent* would be the *walk* of *Parent*. But this is not the case in your code so the *real* type of the instance counts.

Note also the execution would the all the same modifying your *main* to have :

```
public class FirstJava {
public static void main(String[] a) {
    Parent c=new Child();
    c.run();
}
```

because even *c* is declared *Parent* its value is a *Child*

Comment: public void run()
{
    walk();
    System.out.println("Parent run");
}

public void walk()
{
    System.out.println("Parent walk");
}

here when i call walk() its going for walk() of Child. 
Why not for walk() of parent?
while calling walk() which object its refering to and why??

Please anyone explain.

Comment: @VijayGawas I edited my answer, is it ok for you now ?

Comment: @VijayGawas so ?

Answer (score 0):

*If you override a parent method in its child, child objects will always use the overridden version.*